# Redux Saga wierd behavior on Join effect

Tags: redux, babeljs, redux-saga

```
const tasks = yield [fork(method1), fork(method2)]
```

**Working**

`yield tasks.map(task => join(task))`

**Not working and showing error** *argument 0 is not a valid Task object*

`yield tasks.map(join)`

Any body has idea why it is not working. I am using Babel ES6 transpiler so this issue might be related to transpiler thing.

Comment: I think it is something related to Babel transpiler.

Comment: did u find a answer for this?

Comment: not yet find the reason of this behavior

Comment: Is this still an issue? If so, you should raise it as a bug on their GitHub.